# Add one single value at index zero to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

My data looks like this:

```
[Decimal('0.000002071654381756182852502351328')
 Decimal('0.000002110826853094894332007734070')
 Decimal('0.000002156664416546792069513607474')]
```

computed thanks to:
`sorted_array = np.sort(df['spread%'])`.

Simple question, I would like to add the value 0.0 at index 0 in my array, how to proceed? I tried with `np.insert(a,sorted_array, 0.0)` but did not work...any idea? Thanks

Comment: Please provide a full [mcve], not a partial one.

Comment: `np.insert` should work. `np.insert(a,rray 0, 0.0)`. Show what you have tried so we can see what is wrong

Comment: This is what I tried: `np.insert(a,sorted_array, 0.0)` not sure I am using it correctly, I do not really understand the doc...

Comment: `np.insert(sorted_array, 0, 0.0)`

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks!